# How to deliver an AWS interview assignment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I received an assignment from a company. For that assignment, I created a Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream, S3 buckets, a Lambda function, table and views in Athena, and a Quicksight dashboard by using the AWS console web site.
Then I developed a Python script for sending test data to the Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream

The company requested an easily reproducible environment.

- I created a virtual environment and requirements.txt file for the Python code.
- How can I create a reproducible environment for the AWS user, role, policies, lambda function and all resources (stream, buckets etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: CloudFormation, Terraform are just some examples of such tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a reproducible AWS environment, you have to leverage a concept called **Infrastructure as Code (IaC)**. Using native AWS, this can be done using [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation) (declarative, using JSON or YAML) or the [AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) (imperative, using TypeScript, JavaScript, Python, Java, or C#).

> **AWS CloudFormation** provides a common language for you to model and provision AWS and third party application resources in your cloud environment.

> The **AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK)** is an open source software development framework to model and provision your cloud application resources using familiar programming languages.

---

*As a side note: If you're interviewing for a non-entry-level job involving AWS (which I assume, since you're expected to build something using Kinesis Firehose, Lambda functions, Athena, etc.), please be aware that you should be very familiar with the basic cloud concepts, like IaC.*